# Accessing object's method from Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

My Exchange body is a HashMap

```
public void processHeathData(@Body HashMap<String, Object> body)
{

    CompleteTxnDetail competeTxnDetail = getCompeteTxn();
    competeTxnDetail.setTxnDataMap(txnDataMap);
    body.put("NOW", competeTxnDetail);
}
```

I put a object in map

```
public class CompleteTxnDetail {
public float getTotalFaliurePercentage()
{
    Set<String> keySet = txnDataMap.keySet();
    Integer totaltxn = getTotalTxn();
    if(totaltxn==0)
        return 0;

    Integer faliure=0;
    for(String key : keySet)
    {
        TransactionStatusDetailDTO dto = txnDataMap.get(key);
        faliure = faliure + dto.getFailedTxn();
    }

    float faliurePercentage = faliure*100f/totaltxn;
    return faliurePercentage;       
}
}
```

Now I am accessing this in when but unable to access

```
   <choice>
    <camel:when>
        <simple>${body.NOW.getTotalFaliurePercentage} &lt; 2</simple>
        <bean ref="test" method="printMessage('One')" />
    </camel:when>
    <camel:otherwise>
            <bean ref="test" method="printMessage('two')" />
    </camel:otherwise>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you getting error messages?

Comment: I am gettin can't call method on NULL, I also tried ${body[NOW].getTotalFaliurePercantage $lt; 2}

Comment: Are you putting a MAP on the exchange body and trying to access it from a simple statement? I am not sure that works. I normally use processors for that.

Comment: Unmarshalling a dataformat like [Flatpack](http://camel.apache.org/flatpack-dataformat.html) creates an exchange of type  List<Map<String, Object>> which you access an individual value with <simple>${body.get(0).get("FileSize")}</simple> so I suspect you might be able to do something like this ${body.get("NOW").getTotalFaliurePercantage()}

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
<simple>${body.get('NOW').getTotalFaliurePercentage()} &lt; 2</simple>
```